# Updates are not written in Database in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In `manage.py`:

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager, Shell
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db
from app.models import *


app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
manager.add_command('shell', Shell(use_ipython=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I have a model with:

```
...
class Edge(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'edges'

    sources = db.Column(
        db.ARRAY(db.String),
        server_default="{}"
    )
    ...
```

Then I run `python manage.py shell` and within the shell

```
e = Edge.query.first()
assert len(e.sources) == 0
e.sources.append('hello')
db.session.add(e)
db.session.commit()
```

But then closing the shell and going back in, this very edge still has no source (`e.sources` is `[]`)

---

Also tried

```
db.session.object_session(e).add(e)
db.session.object_session(e).commit()
```

---

I noticed that after `db.session.commit()`, `e.sources` is `[]` again!

```
e = Edge.query.first()
assert len(e.sources) == 0
e.sources.append('hello')
e.sources
>>> ['hello']
db.session.add(e)
db.session.commit()
e.sources
>>>[]
```

Can it have anything to do with the `server_default` in the `Column` definition?

Comment: You missed a commit().

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem, using commit does not change my problem  I'll update

Comment: The `db.session.add(e)` calls are redundant, since `e` is already in the session.